# Store data in JSON and show it in table

Tags: javascript, json

I'm very new to coding and my first project is creating a table that will work for a social I'm hosting. 
This is a table, where you can put an input and it will add it to the table. My code is:

```
function addToTable() {
    var table = document.getElementById("mainTable");
    var song = document.getElementById("songInput").value;
    var reason = document.getElementById("reasonInput").value;
    var team = document.getElementById("teamInput").value;
    var dataArray = [song, reason, team];
    console.log("Song input is " + song)
    console.log("Reason input is " + reason)
    console.log("Team input is " + team)

    for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++){
        var today = new Date();
        var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
        var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
        var songCell = row.insertCell(i);
        var reasonCell = row.insertCell(i);
        var teamCell = row.insertCell(i);i
        var timeCell = row.insertCell(3);
        songCell.innerText = song;
        reasonCell.innerText = reason;
        teamCell.innerText = team;
        timeCell.innerText = time;

    }
}
```

Obviously with HTML and stuff.
My question is, how do I store the data I receive (team, song, reason) in a JSON string and how do I show that in the table?
Because my problem now is, everything will be added to the table but as soon as the page is reloaded, it will dissapear.
My other question would be - how do I make it so this can be seen in more than one screen? as this table will take requests and then the DJ from another computer will see them, play them and remove them from the table. So i'd like for the table to be seen in multiple screens and also hopefully be updated every 1 minute? or 3?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want this to be shown on more than one screen? Why not try storing it in `window.localStorage` and retrieving it on a separate page. It's unreliable, but it could work in lieu of storing it in a database.

Comment: if you want the data you enter to be available to people using different computers/devices, then you need a more complete web application solution utilising server-side code and a storage repository (e.g. a database, or a file on the server at the very least). Your web page would have contain a form (or some JavaScript code which makes an AJAX request) to post that data to a URL on the server, where the server-side code processes it and stores it. And then you need another URL where someone can visit that URL and the server script retrieves the stored data and displays it.

Comment: Start here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture#Three-tier_architecture